# Local repository for *.whl files python

Tags: python, pypi

I'm new to python and I need to install *.whl files locally from some folder (repository). I can install *whl like by using the command `pip install path_to_file/*.whl`, but this is not I want, what I do want is to write `pip install some_whl_package` and install the package specified from LOCAL directory. How can I do it? I use python 3.8.

Comment: I am not sure i got your question right.You don't want pip to install from the network but from the local repository, Am i right?

Comment: Yes you're right

Answer (score 0):

Note that the dist folder must contain the whl file.you can also install .tar.gz packages like this

```
pip install --no-index -f ./dist my_package.whl
```

Comment: Ok, but what if my_package.whl also depends on others *.whl packages and they are in dist folder too. It will install them automatically or will be trying to find them in internet?